# How do I get a LazyComboBox to select an item from another page in Vaadin?

Tags: combobox, lazy-loading, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I am using `Vaadin 7.5.5` and `Viritin 1.35`.  I have implemented a `LazyComboBox` that is backed by a `Spring Data JPA` service call and repository.

My basic setup for the LazyComboBox is:

```
    initList(
            Site.class,
            new FilterablePagingProvider() {
                @Override
                public List findEntities(int index, String name) {
                    return sitesService.findByName(name);
                }
            },
            new FilterableCountProvider() {
                @Override
                public int size(String name) {
                    return sitesService.countByName(name);
                }
            },
            PAGE_SIZE
    );
```

This works great when I am typing in the combo box.
If I pick an item from the first page (page 0) I can then leave the combo box, come back to it, and click the drop down arrow again and the previously selected item is still selected.

However, if I choose an item from any page other than 0, then clicking the drop down arrow causes the selected item to become `null` and the user has to find the original item again.

I can post the details of the service and repository if needed but it isn't anything more complicated than a `select * from table where name like '%' + name + '%'`.

How do I keep the selected value in the combo box no matter what page was chosen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `setNullSelectionAllowed(false);` on this combo box.

Also, a solution to keep selected value after navigation can be to store it in a session value, then you'll be able to retreive it wherever you are. [See Session wiki page](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Setting+and+reading+session+attributes)